# Understanding attachEvents

Tags: javascript, extjs, dom-events

I mean the one in Ext.grid.feature.Feature;
it is used for example in the grid Filters Plug in.

I've been looking in the source code but I can't find where is it called from.

I'd be very grateful if someone could answer me exactly how it works and which class or function calls it.

It would help me and others to understand this and other plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `Ext.view.Table#attachEventsForFeatures`. (This is Ext 4.0.2a.) Discovery path: the `Ext.grid.Panel` class uses a view internally to render the actual grid table, which is `Ext.grid.View`. This class extends `Ext.view.Table` which provides most of the 'feature' support. Another important class that provides hooks into the table markup generation is `Ext.view.TableChunker`.